# send different mails to different recipients using SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am trying to send mass emails using SwiftMailer , so far i am able to send single email successfully.

But the problem is i want to send `different Messages` to `different Recipients`  from my database.

I know how to add multiple recipients using `$message->addTo` function but what about different messages content that we used to set using `$message->setBody` in a `batch send`.

so how can i send different messages to different recipients in a batch mode ?

here is format of my email , consider i am sending job matching profiles to 100 different users and each 100 different users has a different content

```
<User Name> <Email Address>


               <Job Matching Title 1>
               <Job Description>

               <Job Matching Title 2>
               <Job Description>                   

               <Job Matching Title 3>
               <Job Description>
```

Comment: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#decorator-plugin ??

Comment: @HappyApe this helped me , you can post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment, Decorator plugin could help you to achieve that -

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#decorator-plugin

Glad that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the message is customised, you will have to generate and send individual emails.

See if you can do what you are asking for in Outlook or any other email client.  If you cant there, then you cant here as well.

Comment: then how other softwares can do that for example if they want to send different 100 results to different 100 recipient ?

Comment: they generate each email individually.

Comment: so i have to create new mailer instance everytime ? using `$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);`